# How to find out which software installed Adaware

Tags: windows-10, unwanted-application

So I suddenly have Adaware Web Companion installed on my (Windows 10) computer, not of my own doing. How can I find out which application decided to install it so that I can remove that application and rubbish them? It may have been a sneaky installer option but I am just not sure.

Comment: Have you tried to sort your list of installed apps by date in control panel? The one installed/updated the same day as Adaware may be the culprit.

Comment: ^ This! If you installed Program A on 26th April, and Adaware is right above it, there's your answer.

Comment: Using this method, it turns out this is the only software I have that was installed on the 16th Feb, with nothing else for days either side of it. I may have installed and subsequently uninstalled the offending application. Is there any way to get a record of it?

Comment: Check your user temp folder for any logs that may exist for the installation.